# Sending 450 e-mails, how much time should be required? Any other solutions available?

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm sending a lot of e-mails (like a newsletter) through a web page. This is news that should be sent when the secretary press "insert and send through e-mail".

Because the server do not support chronjobs or similar things, I split the e-mail sending into a "refreshing" page that sends 5 e-mails every refresh, to avoid spam filters and to send e-mail on client request.

Now, I'm using a phpmailer script (notice that the code I've written is quite old, like 4-5 years ago), that uses smtp server to send e-mail.

How much time should require to send all 450 e-mails approximatively? I calculated around 5 seconds per e-mail, so should take around 35 minutes. Because of the "refreshing page" I don't have any trouble with time_limit for php.

Am I wrong? Should PHPMailer sends e-mail faster?

I were thinking about suggesting my client to buy a mailing list service, however the biggest problem is that the mailing list should be build through my php code, because it fetches a lot of data from the database and collect users from there.

What solutions are available for this?

Comment: Be warned, you will most likely end up on black-lists. Please google sending mass E-mail before you go ahead.

Comment: Use a third service like mailchimp or mailjet instead of doing this on your own.

Comment: @j0k: Do they allow me to send an e-mail built from php? I need to build text from the database, really.

Comment: @RobertIlbrink: That's why I'm asking. Anyway I'm using a valid SMTP Server that is a real e-mail.

Comment: @Fire-Dragon-DoL For mailjet, yes (I know that since I use it) https://www.mailjet.com/docs/api and I guess that other one also have an API.

Comment: Is even possible to make questions on this website?! I'm asking how to send a lot of e-mails through PHP, I think it's a valid and objective question, we even have a valid answer. Anyway, Mailjet looks nice, but the pricing is a bit "high", I mean, they are missing a mid-level service (after bronze for 7 $ they have a 74$ service?!)

Comment: I think the service isn't primarily offered for 450 emails. More likely for websites that will send out 4,500,000 emails each day ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using services like mailgun.com, postageapp.com, mailchimp.com or postmarkapp.com for those purposes? They all have a nice documented PHP API.

Comment: That's interesting, if they allows me to build mails from database, I'm ok with them.

Comment: No, you have to do build the email from that. They will only handle the processment of the email delivery.

Comment: I would suggest you to use Postmark. You will get 1,000 free credits (= 1,000 emails to send) and can simply send via their SMTP gateway. Have a look here: http://developer.postmarkapp.com/developer-smtp.html

Comment: I'm looking for it, let me check.

Comment: The question is closed and I won't have other answers, still I find this the correct one. You gave me enough suggestions.